# ASP.NET MVC: Html.Actionlink() generates empty link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-routing

Okay i'm experiencing some problems with the actionlink htmlhelper.

I have some complicated routing as follows:

```
        routes.MapRoute("Groep_Dashboard_Route", // Route name
                        "{EventName}/{GroupID}/Dashboard", // url with Paramters
                        new {controller = "Group", action="Dashboard"});

        routes.MapRoute("Event_Groep_Route", // Route name
                        "{EventName}/{GroupID}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

My problem is generating action links that match these patterns.
The eventname parameter is really just for having a user friendly link. it doesn't do anything.

Now when i'm trying for example to generate a link. that shows the dashboard of a certain groep. 
Like:

```
  mysite.com/testevent/20/Dashboard
```

I'll use the following actionlink:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Show dashboard", "Group", "Dashboard",  new { EventName_Url = "test", GroepID = item.groepID}, null)%>
```

What my actual result in html gives is:

```
 <a href="">Show Dashboard</a>
```

What i should have is something like:

```
 <a href="test/20/Dashboard">Show Dashboard</a>
```

Please bear with me i'm still new at ASP MVC. Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here, aside from what has already been pointed out - you've also got the Controller and Action strings around the wrong way.

This method signature you are after looks like this:

```
HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

So your one needs to be:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Show dashboard", "Dashboard", "Group", new { EventName = "test", GroupID = item.groupID}, null) %>
```

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Yea!. The wrongly spelled stuff is because i wanted to translate the  code a lil bit to english & make it more clear.

The problem was indeed i turned around controller & action. Stupid mistake. Sorry for bothering you all with such a dumb question

Tnx alot

Comment: Mate, don't be so hard on yourself... we all have our fair share of pebkac moments! Keep posting questions no matter how easy or hard they seem to be :-) Ps. pebkac = [p]roblem [e]xists [b]etween [k]eyboard [a]nd [c]hair

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that it doesn't find a route that match those parameters. You have misspelled GroupID and you have entered a route parameter that doesn't exist ("EventName_Url") in the route you are trying to match. The actionlink should probably look something like this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Show dashboard", "Group", "Dashboard",  new { EventName = "test", GroupID = item.groepID}, null)%
```